# difficulty understanding exercise 1.4.6 in serge lange's complex analysis text

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi: I'm going through the exercises in Serge Lange's book and I have the solutions but
I still don't understand the answer to exercise 1.4.6.

I will state the question and then skip a few lines for people who want to try to answer
without seeing the answer.

The question is:  Let $f(z) = lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{z^{n}}{1+ z^{n}}$.

a) What is the domain of definition of $f$, that is, for which complex numbers $z$ does the limit exist.

b) Give explicitly the values of $f(z)$ for the various $z$ in the domain of $f$.

I will skip a few lines and then write the answer below.

### --

### --

### --

### --

Solution:

A) If $|z| < 1$, then $z^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ so $f(z) = 0$.

That makes sense to me.

B) If $|z| > 1$, then $f(z) = 1$ because $|\frac{z^n}{z^n+1} - 1 | = \frac{1}{|z^{n}+1|}
\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

This also makes sense to me.

Then, they say the following: "We then investigate what happens on the unit circle.
Let $z = e^{i\theta}$ with $0 <= \theta <= 2\pi$. Then, $1 + z^{n} = 1 + e^{in\theta}$.

So, if $\theta = 0$, we immediately get $f(z) = \frac{1}{2}$.

All of that makes sense too.

Then it says: If $\theta \ne 0$, then $f(z) = \frac{e^{n i \theta}}{1 + e^{n i \theta}} 
= \frac{1}{1 + e^{-n i \theta}}$ and since $e^{-n i \theta}$ goes around the circle, we
cannot define $f$ at the points $z = e^{i \theta}$ with $\theta \ne 0$. So, if $\Omega$
denotes the unit circle minus the point $1$, we see that the domain of definition of
$f$ is the set $C - \Omega$.

Could someone explain this last part ? I don't understand why $f$ can't be defined at the points ? nor do I see how they obtain $f$. Thanks in advance for your help. stackexchange is truly an amazing place. I wish it existed when I was in college. I'd probably would
have learned a lot more !!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z$ is on the unit circle, and $z\neq1$, then $z^n/(1+z^n)$ is not even a Cauchy sequence.
$f(z)=z^n/(1+z^n)=e^{in\theta}/(1+e^{in\theta})$.  Divide top and bottom by $e^{in\theta}$ and you get $1/(e^{-in\theta}+1)$.
When you go from $n$ to $n+1$, $e^{-in\theta}$ changes value by a factor $e^{-i\theta}$, so the difference $e^{-(n+1)\theta}-e^{-n\theta}$ has absolute value $2\sin(\theta/2)$.  I should draw the unit circle here, with an angle $\theta$ between two points on the circle.

Lastly, $|1+e^{-in\theta}|<2$ so its reciprocal changes by an amount at least half that.  Since the sequence changes from term to term by at least $\sin(\theta/2)$, it does not converge, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: gotcha michael.  that's very clear. now i see it. it's just going to go around and around and never converge to anything. thanks so much.